# Application freezes while reading from file in C++

Tags: c++, file

so this is my text file:

```
Computer Science
4
345848534
1 
Ivan Ivanov
Georgi Georgiev
Plamen Angelov
======
Oreily
5th avenue, London
44384208434
*****************
Biology
2
58934673
0 
Georgi Ivanov
Nikolay Stamatov
Jack Johnson
======
Head first
Stanley Str 4, Manchester
449348344
```

And this is my function to read from the file:

```
void ApprovedBook::read_from_file() {
fstream file;
string heading; int edition; long ISBN = 0L; bool isApproved = 0; // temp values   for each book 
string name; string address; long telephone = 0L; // temp values for manufacturer of the book
vector<string> authors; // temp vector for authors of the book  
string line;

file.open("books.txt", ios::in | ios::app);

while (file.good()) {
    for (int i=1; i<=NUM_ITEMS; i++) { 
        getline(file, line);
        switch (i) {
        case 1: 
            heading = line; break;
        case 2:
            edition = atoi(line.c_str()); break;
        case 3:
            ISBN = atol(line.c_str()); break;
        case 4:
            isApproved = (bool) atoi(line.c_str()); break;
        }
    }

    getline(file, line);
    while (line != "======") {
        authors.push_back(line);
        getline(file,line);
    }

    int i = 1;
    getline(file, line);
    while (line != "*****************") {
        switch (i) {
        case 1: 
            name = line; break;
        case 2:
            address = line; break;
        case 3: 
            telephone = atol(line.c_str()); break;
        }

        getline(file, line);
        i++;
    }

    Manufacturer m(name, address, telephone);
    ApprovedBook a(heading, authors, edition, ISBN, m, isApproved);
    cout << a << endl;
    authors.clear();
}

file.close();
}
```

So I separate the information needed to construct an "ApprovedBook" object with the ********* line. The lines between "=====" and the stars are needed to construct a "Manufacturer" object which is a property of ApprovedBook as well. So I read the first piece information and output the object with << (i have predefined the operator for the class). But after that the application freezes and doesn't seem to read the next piece of information which is below the the stars. What's the problem with that? Is the file.good() condition enough or maybe some more advanced check is needed ?

Comment: `ios::in | ios::app` makes no sense, the flags are mutually exclusive.

Comment: i left ios::in only but nothing changes.

Comment: [`while (!stream.eof())` and `while (stream.good())` are almost always wrong](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.5) (Where do these keep coming from?!?!?!?!?!)

Comment: so what do you suggest for a condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced file.good with while (line != "") and that worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

`while (line != "*****************") {` will always be true for the last record, unless you add stars at the end of the input file.

Comment: I added the stars, now it reads the second piece as well but still freezes.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you'll need this line to check your file as well:

```
while (file.good() && line != "*****************") {
```

Comment: That way it reads only the first part of the file. I considered adding some special line like "_________" or something else to mark the end of the file but since i will be adding information later this won't work. I wonder if all these checks for EOF like !file.eof or file.good() don't work then what would...